# How can I show my data from database in Multi-line TextBox line by line?

Tags: c#, .net, textbox

I have tried below code. It is run successfully but showing result as "System.Data.DataView" in txtQueue(Text box) but not the data.

```
 try
 {
    AddURL objAddurls = new AddURL();
    objAddurls.ExecuteSql("select sURL from addurl where iStatus=1 AND iLicenseID='" + CommonMethods.iLicenseID + "'");
    txtQueueURLs.Text = objAddurls.DefaultView.ToString();
 }

 catch (Exception ee)
 {

 }
```

could any body tell me please what's wrong with this code or suggest me new code?
thanks in Advance.

Comment: AddURL is my table in Database i am using store procedure through my generation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I show my data from database in Multi-line TextBox line by
>   line?

There are few ways to retrieve data form database and this is jut one of them, what method will you choose is not important.

Writing data to a textBox, line by line, can be achieved by setting *textBox.Multiline* property to true and adding *Environment.NewLine* to *textBox.Text* every time you need new line.

Here is the example code that might help you:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace StackTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\Projects;Initial Catalog=DbTest;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False";
            string selectString = "select * from TblTest";
            textBox1.Multiline = true;

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectString,conn);

            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                textBox1.Text += rdr[0];
                textBox1.Text += rdr[1];
                //...
                textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
            }

            conn.Close();                 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Milan-j its working for me,I just comment TextBox1.Text+=rdr[1] and run successfully, giving me result in Multi-Line text box.

Comment: That's because you only have one column in the database table. Instead of numbers you can also use string as index like this rdr["columnName"]. You should read more about SqlDataReader type here... http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson04
Glad that I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the ToString method on [DataView.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7k4xfbd.aspx) which returns the name of the component. I think you want to iterate through the rows within the DefaultView and assign the TextBox value to that.

```
 StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();
 foreach (DataRowView rowView in objAddurls.DefaultView)
  {
   DataRow row = rowView.Row;
   // build a string from your row //
  }

txtQueueURLs.Text = sb.ToString()
```